# rename a batch of files after reading from a source file

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, rename

I have a directory full of over a thousand files and the names are bit long (and no pattern found in the naming style). I would like to simplify the filenames. E.g.:

```
Bioimage_23335989_Data_22317866_22317867_20140723_1002.pdb
Bioimage_22335990_Data_22318490_22318491_20140723_1009.pdb
Bioimage_23835970_Data_22317866_22317867_20140723_1005.pdb
```

.....and so on !

I have made a simple text file (`filelist.txt`) which reads like this:

```
1.pdb   Bioimage_23335989_Data_22317866_22317867_20140723_1002.pdb
2.pdb   Bioimage_22335990_Data_22318490_22318491_20140723_1009.pdb
3.pdb   Bioimage_23835970_Data_22317866_22317867_20140723_1005.pdb
```

.....and so on !

Can anybody provide me with a script (`awk`, `sed`, etc) which would read the source file and rename the files accordingly? I could get similar scripts else where but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Shell variable expansions with wildcards and the `mv` command should be enough to manage this.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, [Mass Rename python script](https://github.com/no-time/rename), or another AU user script might help [too](https://github.com/lucio-martinez/rch)

Answer (score 2):

No awk or sed necessary, since your `filelist.txt` is already in the perfect format.

A few things in advance… I presume that there is no whitespace in the file names, and that a space separates the two filenames on each line. Also, I assume that `filelist.txt` [terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline) with a EOL before the EOF.

Of course, make a backup of the directory before running this command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/pdb_files
while read -r line; do
  mv $line
done < /path/to/filelist.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `while read -r line; do`: This iterates through each line of the file, putting each line into the variable `$line`.
- `mv $line`: As each line contains two filenames seperated by a space, we can pass the arguments directly to `mv`. i.e. it'll immediately move files from the first filename to the second.

---

### EDIT

I just re-read your question. I interpreted it as you wanting to rename files from (e.g.) `1.pdb` to `Bioimage_23335989_Data_22317866_22317867_20140723_1002.pdb`. I'm not sure if you wanted it the other way around. If so, then the following script would work instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/pdb_files
while read -r line; do
  mv $(awk '{print $2, $1}' <<<$line)
done < /path/to/filelist.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `mv $(awk '{print $2, $1}' <<<$line)`: Read from `$line`, and print the second field followed by the first field. Pass these two filenames as parameters to `mv`.

Comment: I think that `mv` requires two arguments.

Comment: @Warwick, Yep, it does. Each `$line` has two arguments in it.

Comment: My bad. I should have checked the input :-)

Comment: No worries @user3810095. If it works, please accept. :)

Comment: saved  me from lots of trouble you script works like charm

Answer (score 0):

```
while read tname fname
do
  mv ${fname} ${tname}
done < filelist.txt
```